# Exec into temp table without columns as they are dynamic

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on pivot functionality, where the pivot columns comes dynamically. All the pivot columns I needs to count and display separate column in pivot select statement itself.

```
SELECT CurriculumSegment,attendancedate,section,Class,count(*) as 
TotalWorkingDays into #NewTempWithTotalDaysCount
   FROM  #temp1 group by CurriculumSegment,attendancedate,Section,Class 
   order by  CurriculumSegment, attendancedate,Class,Section

SELECT CurriculumSegment,attendancedate,section,Class,count(*) as 
CountOfPresentDays into #NewTempWithTotalPresentDaysCount
   FROM  #temp1 where attendance='P' group by 
 CurriculumSegment,attendancedate,Section,Class order by CurriculumSegment, 
attendancedate,Class,Section


select a.AttendanceDate,a.Class,a.CurriculumSegment,
a.Section,a.TotalWorkingDays,b.CountOfPresentDays,(a.TotalWorkingDays - 
b.CountOfPresentDays) as TotalAbsentDays, (b.CountOfPresentDays * 
 100)/a.TotalWorkingDays as PercentOfPresentDays
into #TempWithTotalDaysCount 
from #NewTempWithTotalDaysCount a left outer join 
#NewTempWithTotalPresentDaysCount b 
on a.AttendanceDate =b.AttendanceDate and a.CurriculumSegment = 
 b.CurriculumSegment and a.Section= b.Section and a.Class = b.Class

-- Query 1
select  sum(TotalWorkingDays) as TotalCount,sum(TotalAbsentDays) as 
AbsentCount,sum(CountOfPresentDays) as 
PresentCount,curriculumsegment,section,class 
from #TempWithTotalDaysCount group by class,curriculumsegment,section

SET @query = 'SELECT [CurriculumSegment],Class,section,'+@cols+'
FROM ( 
SELECT [CurriculumSegment],
Class,section,PercentOfPresentDays,AttendanceDate  FROM 
#TempWithTotalDaysCount) AS up 
PIVOT (MAX(PercentOfPresentDays) FOR AttendanceDate IN ('+@cols+')) AS pvt' 

-- Query 2
EXEC (@query)
```

From the query 1 and query 2 results, I needs to do join and get the TotalCount, AbsentCount, PresentCount
in the result of query 2.

Is it possible to put  "EXEC(@query)" in temp table ?
I tried but I'm getting invalid object. Because I cant give the column names as they come dynamically form pivot.
So,is there any other approach ?

Thank you.

Find out my result in below image:
[image]

Comment: Use global temp table(##) instead of temp table(#).

Comment: Yes, thanks. It helped.

Comment: It's Great. Also mark as useful comment so it helps to other.

Comment: @NP007 Your answer is helpful. Thank you.